# Has the nuclear deal with Iran led to an escalation of Arab differences?

Tags: united-states, iran, saudi-arabia, jcpoa, qatar

[Arab states issue ultimatum to Qatar: close Al-Jazeera, curb ties with **Iran**](http://mobile.reuters.com/article/idUSKBN19E0BB)

The JCPOA agreement between Iran, the P5+1 has shaken the war in Syria In the interests of Iran and Russia.

Has the nuclear deal with Iran led to an escalation of Arab differences?

Comment: "The JCPOA agreement between Obama and Iran has shaken the war in Syria In the interests of Iran and Russia" - Citation Needed

Answer (score 1):

The analysis everywhere links recent developments around Qatar to [the recent travel of Donald Trump to Middle East<sup>1</sup>](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/06/07/middleeast/qatar-crisis-analysis/index.html), **a week before the conflict started**.

While not the root cause of the conflict between Qatar and the other countries, his positioning in favor of Saudi Arabia was interpreted by that government (correctly or not) as a free pass to act against Qatar, which was acting independently of the other Gulf countries.

So:

- No, the root cause of the differences is not the nuclear deal but the political differences between Qatar and other Gulf states.
- No, the detonant of the crisis has not been the nuclear deal but the belief of the Gulf states that the USA would back them or, at the very least, would not support Qatar.

---

<sup>1</sup>Yes, the one he claimed he was going to solve the Middle East conflicts by just talking a little.